# Setting mp3 from RAW folder as a android ringtone, notification and alarm sound

Tags: android, notifications, mp3, android-6.0-marshmallow, ringtone

The final piece for my first (ringtone) app and I have some trouble, based on some tutorial and with a little help from a friend I came up with a code to have mp3 from the RAW folder as an android ringtone, notification, and alarm sound. I tested in on emulator and it worked, but when I tested it on my S6edge+ nothing happened, can someone tell me what could be a problem with this code, or if somebody can point me to a better coding solution

This is the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setSong(this, RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE, R.raw.test, "TestR");
    setSong(this, RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION, R.raw.test, "TestN");
    setSong(this, RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM, R.raw.test, "TestA");
}


/**
 * In this method, we need to copy the mp3 file to the sd card location from
 * where android picks up ringtone files
 * After copying, we make the mp3 as current ringtone
 *
 * @param context
 * @param type
 * @param songId
 * @param ringtoneTitle
 * @return
 */

public static boolean setSong(Context context, int type, int songId, String ringtoneTitle) {
    byte[] buffer = null;
    InputStream fIn = context.getResources().openRawResource(
            songId);
    int size = 0;

    try {
        size = fIn.available();
        buffer = new byte[size];
        fIn.read(buffer);
        fIn.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return false;
    }

    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
            + "/media/audio/ringtones/";

    String filename = ringtoneTitle + ".mp3";

    boolean exists = (new File(path)).exists();
    if (!exists) {
        new File(path).mkdirs();
    }

    FileOutputStream save;
    try {
        save = new FileOutputStream(path + filename);
        save.write(buffer);
        save.flush();
        save.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        return false;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return false;
    }

    context.sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE,
            Uri.parse("file://" + path + filename)));

    File k = new File(path, filename);

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, k.getAbsolutePath());
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, ringtoneTitle);
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/*");
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.SIZE, k.length());

    // This method allows to change Notification and Alarm tone also. Just
    // pass corresponding type as parameter
    if (RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE == type) {
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, true);
    } else if (RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION == type) {
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, true);
    } else if (RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM == type) {
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, true);
    }

    Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(k.getAbsolutePath());

    String selection = MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA + " =?";
    String[] selectionArgs = {k.getAbsolutePath()};
    Uri newUri = null;

    // Check if record exist
    Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, null, selection, selectionArgs, null);
    if (c != null) {
        if (c.getCount() > 0) {
            // Record exist
            // Update record
            while (c.moveToNext()) {
                int idIndex = c.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID);
                int dataIndex = c.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA);
                String strId = c.getString(idIndex);
                String songPath = c.getString(dataIndex);
                newUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(songPath);
                String condition = MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID + " =?";
                String[] selectionArg = {strId};
                context.getContentResolver().update(uri, values, condition, selectionArg);
            }

        } else {
            // Record does not exist, create new
            newUri = context.getContentResolver().insert(uri, values);
        }
    }

    if (newUri != null) {
        RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(context, type,
                newUri);
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

}

of course, I got permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>`
```

and a test.mp3 file in raw folder

Comment: Check permissions  for marshmallow

Comment: i have tried this and also implements runtime permission. i am getting the following error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You cannot keep your settings in the secure settings. –

Answer (score 0):

> Beginning in Android 6.0 (API level 23), users grant permissions to apps while the app is running, not when they install the app. This approach streamlines the app install process, since the user does not need to grant permissions when they install or update the app. It also gives the user more control over the app's functionality; for example, a user could choose to give a camera app access to the camera but not to the device location. The user can revoke the permissions at any time, by going to the app's Settings screen.

You will need to handle runtime permission in your application.
Refer to the below link for a tutorial.
[Runtime Permission in Android](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

Comment: I don't think that was the case, I have downloaded an app from Google Play and run it on the same phone and it didn't asked for any permissions while it was setting the ringtone, so that could not be the case

Comment: i have tried this and also implements runtime permission.

i am getting the following error:

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You cannot keep your settings in the secure settings.

Comment: Your application does not have access to `WRITE_SETTINGS` permission. You need ask the user to explicitly grant the permission by launching the setting screen. You could use the `Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_WRITE_SETTINGS` action to launch the screen

[Reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#WRITE_SETTINGS)